# Retrofit 2: @FormUrlEncoded with default fields

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I need to send a request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header. The response is list of some music albums in JSON format. There can be two optional parameter: **total** (default value = 5) and **begin** (default value = 0)

Here is the interface I use to send this request:

```
public interface MusicService {
    @Headers("Accept: Application/JSON")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("album/featured-albums")
    Call<List<Album>> listFeaturedAlbums(@Field("total") int total, @Field("begin") int begin);
}
```

The question is, how can I set default value to one or both of these fields, so that I don't have to send the parameters in each request. For example I want to get 30 items on every request and just play with **begin** field. Or maybe I want to use the default values for both fields:

```
public interface MusicService {
    @Headers("Accept: Application/JSON")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("album/featured-albums")
    Call<List<Album>> listFeaturedAlbums();
}
```

With this, I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Form-encoded method must contain at least one @Field.

Comment: Retrofit 2 supports passing null as an argument and will just not include that field. So with your first interface would just be mMusicService.listFeaturedAlbums(null, null). You'd have to use Integer instead of int as the parameter type

Comment: I'm aware of this option. Isn't there a more concise way for doing this?

Comment: Did you try using `@Default`? `@Default("totalDefaultValue") (@Field("total") int total`

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin, `@Default` is unknown.

Comment: @CoolMind, use default constructor instead.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment I don't think you can do it in a non-hackish way this.

Guys at retrofit are working on adding this functionality: [Allow specifying default @Field values. #951](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/951)

You can follow this thread when it will complete. Or help them out and submit a PR :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Call<List<Album>> listFeaturedAlbums(@Body CustomFields );

class CustomFields {
 String total;
 String begin = 0;
 public CustomFields( String total ) {
   this.total = total;
 }
...
getters&setters
..
}
```

Comment: What does this means? Why you didn't explained your code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the request header like this :

```
 @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

it's working for me